# Give an icon to dynamic array elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic number of arrays like `[1,2,3,5,7]`, `[1,2,3]`, `[2,7,8]` ...  where the elements represent a platform id which helps to identify platforms like PlayStation, Xbox etc. uniquely...

I want to link a [react-icon](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons) to each element of the array such that each symbol gets linked to the id of the platform it represents, for eg:
if platform id of playstation is `2` i want `<FaPlaystation/>` icon linked to it so that i can display it in my react card component, basically something like this:
[image]

how do i implement this in react? I'm getting platform ids via a prop called plat, upon iterating it like this :

```
let platMain = plat.map(plat=>plat.platform.id);
```

i get the array of ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (not to be confused with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) to be later used to lookup the associated icon component by the numeric key provided.

```
import { FaAndroid, FaAngular, FaReact, FaDev } from "react-icons/fa";

const map1 = new Map([
  [1, FaAndroid],
  [2, FaAngular],
  [3, FaReact],
  [4, FaDev]
]);

const platMain = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {platMain.map((key) => {
        const icon = map1.get(key);
        return icon ? icon() : null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit admiring-jones-d010x]

---

Or similar with a plain old Object with numeric keys.

```
import { FaAndroid, FaAngular, FaReact, FaDev } from "react-icons/fa";

const map = {
  1: FaAndroid,
  2: FaAngular,
  3: FaReact,
  4: FaDev
};

const platMain = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {platMain.map((key) => {
        const icon = map[key];
        return icon ? icon() : null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit solitary-water-4zv3n]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
// utility to get Icon
const getPlatformIcon = (platformId) => {
  switch (platformId) {
    case 1:
       return <FaIconName />
    case 2:
       return <FaPlaystation/>
    case 3:
       return <FaAnotherIconName />
    default:
       return <FaDefaultIcon /> // or return null if you don't have it
  }
}

// your component
export default function({plat}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        plat.map(p => getPlatformIcon(p.platform.id))
      }
    </div>

  )



}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this method would be better:

```
const yourArray = [
{id: 2, icon: <FaPlaystation /> },
{id: 4, icon: <AnotherIcon />},
{id: 6, icon: <AnotherIcon />}
]

//then

{yourArray.map((item)=>(
<div>
<p>item.id</p>
{item.icon}
</div>
))}
```